# What is YouTube's NEW Live Stream permanent url?

Tags: url, youtube, embed, live

I was using this url to embed our livestream in our website

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNEL_ID
```

Unfortunately it's not working anymore, I think it has been deprecated by YouTube :(

Any idea what is the alternative?

I want to avoid using the YouTube search API due to it's limitations, and the fact that the broadcast has to start so the API can find it.

Also I don't want to keep updating the url YouTube creates every time I start a stream...

Please help

Comment: I also would like to know, it seems like this is simply gone?

Answer (score 0):

Try with that format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/{CHANNEL_ID}/live
```

It should work.